# Times-itsc style file needed

Tags: fonts

Could you please help me on this..

Where can get the `times-itsc.sty` files?

I found the times italic small caps in the below link:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/progs/italic-small-caps-times-latex

I am getting the error while doing the procedure.

Comment: We are going to need more information. The instructions on the lined page seem clear enough, and you don't say what your error is. Furthermore, italic small caps are rather questionable in general!

Comment: @JosephWright It is good that you are drawing attention to the fact that overdoing markup can be distracting. However I use small caps consistently for certain name-like entities (I won't go into detail here); So if a passage with those is italicized, italic small caps come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

The instructions listed at http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/progs/italic-small-caps-times-latex work fine for me. Please note that you not only need the `times-itsc.sty` file but also several other font files which come all together in one compressed file.

Here again with more details (targeting TeXLive under Linux):

1. Download the font files as Tar.GZ archive file http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/files/times-itsc.tgz
2. Unpack it, e.g. using `tar -xzvf timex-itsc.tgz` in your TEXMF folder, e.g. `~/texmf`.
3. Run `texhash ~/texmf` or make sure there is no `~/texmf/ls-R` file.
4. Compile the following test file:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{times-itsc}
   \begin{document}
   \textsc{Hello \emph{world}}
   \end{document}
   ```

The output should look like:

[image: Result]

If this doesn't work please tell us about your LaTeX installation (OS, TeX-Distribution) and which exact error you got.

Comment: i am using MiKTeX 2.5 Windows HP "Error: initexmf: This utility does not accept non-option arguments." Passed Arguments "mktexlsr --list-formats "E:\times-itsc\times-itsc""

Comment: Just put it in your local TEXMF tree (`c:\localtexmf` or similar I think), open the MikTeX package manager application and press the "update package database" (or similar) button. This should do it for you. I is very important that the file are placed in the correct folder, `E:\timex-itsc` won't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation.. i will get back to u soon..